# Informix SQL 11.5 Put the title on the columns of an unloaded file

Tags: union, informix

Is there a way to make the file from unload more readable?

```
  unload to file1 select * from table1
```

Other than this bad solution:

```
   unload to file1 select * Title1table union select * from table1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to get the column names into the first row of the unloaded data using standard Informix tools.

Your best bet may be to use my `sqlcmd` program. You can find it at the [IIUG — International Informix Users Group](http://www.iiug.org/) web site in the [Software Repository](http://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL). With it, you'd write:

```
sqlcmd -d yourdb -H -e 'unload to file1 select * from table1'
```

and you'd get one line with the column headings (`-H`) and the other lines in UNLOAD format. You could add `-T` to get the column type information too, another line after the names (if both are requested). Both the names and the types are in UNLOAD format.

```sh
sqlcmd -d stores -HT -e 'unload to "elements.unl" select * from elements'
```

The first seven lines of output are:

```
atomic_number|symbol|name|atomic_weight|pt_period|pt_group|stable|
INTEGER|CHAR(3)|CHAR(20)|DECIMAL(8,4)|SMALLINT|CHAR(2)|CHAR(1)|
1|H|Hydrogen|1.0079|1|1|Y|
2|He|Helium|4.0026|1|18|Y|
3|Li|Lithium|6.9410|2|1|Y|
4|Be|Beryllium|9.0122|2|2|Y|
5|B|Boron|10.8110|2|13|Y|
```